# How to verify self signed certificate for https requests using the "requests" module on the client and "flask-restful" on the server (TLS1.2)

Tags: flask, tls1.2, flask-restful, verification, self-signed

Here is what I have so far. Using openssl, I now have these files:
ca.crt, ca.key, ca.srl, server.crt, server.csr, server.key.

I followed this tutorial:
https://carolinafernandez.github.io/development/2017/09/13/HTTPS-and-trust-chain-in-Flask

And now have this as the server:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import psycopg2
import ssl
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# TODO: https security
HTTPS_ENABLED = True
VERIFY_USER = True

API_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
API_PORT = 8000
API_CRT = "server.crt"
API_KEY = "server.key"
API_CA_T = "ca.crt"

context = None
if(HTTPS_ENABLED):
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
    
    if(VERIFY_USER):
        context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
        context.load_verify_locations(API_CA_T)

    try:
        context.load_cert_chain(API_CRT, API_KEY)
    except Exception as e:
        sys.exit("Error starting server: {}".format(e))

...[implementation of api]...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(ssl_context=context, host=API_HOST, port=API_PORT, debug=True)
```

On the client machine, I have this code. I also copied ca.crt over to that machine:

```
import os
import requests
import ssl

def test():
    response = requests.get("https://[url of server]:8000/helloworld", verify='ca.crt')
    #response = requests.get("http://[url of server]:8000/helloworld")
    print(response.text);

def print_version():
    print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
    #print_version()
```

After starting the server api and then running the client code, I get this error message at the client:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='[url of server]', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /helloworld (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```

The purpose of this is so that I can have secure server to server communication. For the foreseeable future, it will literally be one server sending https requests to another server. Am I using the wrong file format for whatever the client has to use to verify? I am not an expert in TLS by any means, so I don't really know the difference between all of the file extensions (I've seen a .pem file being used in verify, for example).

Inside of the link I showed earlier, I also tried the route of producing the client.pem and using that in the verify field.

Answer (score 0):

From the error below, `[url of server]` needs to be like an actual `host` + `port` for example `127.0.0.1:8000`

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='[url of server]', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /helloworld (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))
```